# 2 Virtual Machine on 1 core

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, core

I have a few computer installed with Hyper-V... I running some automatized programs on it... if I using 1 VM/core works like charm... and i can see its not using the 100% of the core... so i thought I can put 2VM/core but when i'm doing that the whole process slowing down terrible and just use 2VM altogether 30-40% of the core... There is anyway to handle/use the processor on the maximum ?

Comment: What CPU do you have? Be as specific as possible, including the model number.

Comment: AMD Athlon II x 2 3GHZ
Intel Celeron CPU G540
Intel Celeron CPU G530
Intel Celeron CPU G645
Xeon X3450
XEON E31120

Comment: Are you sure the system is CPU bound, instead of being disk I/O limited?

Comment: This is a BIOS setting?

Comment: I doubled the virtual core for all VM... so on a dual core processor there is 4 VM with 2 vCPU each. The VMs are XP SP3 and now the processor working between 70-90%.. that is looks acceptable... going to try put an extra VM as well lets see...